# SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network. for IPv6

Tags: java, ipv6, smb, jcifs

The following code throws **SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network.** at canRead()

`String url = "smb://fe80--60ee-226a-4263-53d3s3.ipv6-literal.net/share/path";
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(url);
file.canRead();`

What's the reason?

Comment: Using a link-local address, you must use a scope/interface identifier because every interface uses the same link-local network. Also, an IPv6 URL has the address enclosed in brackets (`[]`).

Comment: In smb url, the scope identifier(%) can be replaced with letter 's'. And we dont need to enclose the address in brackets, as the url here is not an ipv6 address(its ipv6 in literal format,think of it like host name). For more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_UNC_path_names

Comment: I guess it is non-standard, ignoring the published standard: _[RFC 6874, Representing IPv6 Zone Identifiers in Address Literals and Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6874)_.

Comment: thanks, @RonMaupin , does jCIFS supports IPv6 literal given as above? where can i find regarding to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to enclose the IPv6 address within square brackets.
So if, for example, IPv6 address is fe80::60ee:226a:4263:53d3s3. Then the below code will work.

```
String url = "smb://[fe80::60ee:226a:4263:53d3s3]/share/path";
SmbFile file = new SmbFile(url);
file.canRead();
```